# Do comparison on a subset of a subset of a column in awk (EDIT: badly formatted BEGIN)

Tags: awk

I've seen variations of this question which helped me craft an initial guess, mostly involving doing two splits of a column in awk.

Here is an example line of my input:

```
chr1    Cufflinks   transcript  470971  471355  1000    +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000236679.2"; transcript_id "ENST00000458203.2"; FPKM "0.0792422960"; frac "1.000000"; conf_lo "179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000000"; conf_hi "0.000000"; cov "0.233090"; full_read_support "yes";
```

(Yeah, conf_lo is a weird number, but it's a bug in the program used to generate this.)

It is tab-delimited, but one field ($9) is also semicolon and space delimited into key-value pairs. I want to use awk to filter for FPKM values (3 of $9) that are greater than 0, which involves two splits. If the filter passes, it should print a re-arrangement of the whole line. This is my best guess so far:

```
awk -F"\t" 'BEGIN {
OFS="\t";
split($9,t,";"); 
split(t[3],t3,"\""); 
if (t3[2]>0.0) {
print $1,$4,$5,$9,$6,$7;}
}' transcripts.gtf > $input.bed
```

This is probably just a simple misunderstanding somewhere, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got most of it right except that you have written entire script in your `BEGIN` block which means nothing was printed to the screen as no line is read inside of `BEGIN` block.

Try this:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }
{
    split ($9, t, ";"); 
    split (t[3], t3, "\""); 
    if (t3[2]>0.0) {
        print $1, $4, $5, $9, $6, $7
    }
}' transcripts.gtf > $input.bed
```

Having said that you don't need the second `split`. Use the `gsub` function to remove everything except numbers.

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }
{
    split ($9, t, ";");
    gsub (/[^.[:digit:]]+/, "", t[3]);
    if (t[3] > 0) {
        print $1, $4, $5, $9, $6, $7
    }
}' transcripts.gtf > $input.bed
```

You can add `-` inside the character class (`[^.[:digit:]-]`) if your values can be negative.

Comment: Haha, it turns out it was a more fundamental error than not knowing how to split. I think I will edit the title now. Thanks!